# LINQ Expression Tree Any() inside Where()

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression-trees

I'm trying to generate the following LINQ query:

```cs
//Query the database for all AdAccountAlerts that haven't had notifications sent out
//Then get the entity (AdAccount) the alert pertains to, and find all accounts that
//are subscribing to alerts on that entity.
var x = dataContext.Alerts.Where(a => a.NotificationsSent == null)
  .OfType<AdAccountAlert>()
  .ToList()
  .GroupJoin(dataContext.AlertSubscriptions,
    a => new Tuple<int, string>(a.AdAccountId, typeof(AdAccount).Name),
    s => new Tuple<int, string>(s.EntityId, s.EntityType),
    (Alert, Subscribers) => new Tuple<AdAccountAlert, IEnumerable<AlertSubscription>> (Alert, Subscribers))
  .Where(s => s.Item2.Any())
  .ToDictionary(kvp => (Alert)kvp.Item1, kvp => kvp.Item2.Select(s => s.Username));
```

Using Expression Trees (which seems to be the only way I can do this when I need to use reflection and run-time types). Note that in the real code (see below) the AdAccountAlert is actually dynamic through reflection and a for-loop.

**My problem**: I can generate everything up to the .Where() clause. The whereExpression method call blows up because of incompatible types. Normally I know what to put there, but the Any() method call has me confused. I've tried every type I can think of and no luck. Any help with both the .Where() and .ToDictionary() would be appreciated.

Here's what I have so far:

```cs
var alertTypes = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
  .Single(a => a.FullName.StartsWith("Alerts.Entities"))
  .GetTypes()
  .Where(t => typeof(Alert).IsAssignableFrom(t) && !t.IsAbstract && !t.IsInterface);

var alertSubscribers = new Dictionary<Alert, IEnumerable<string>>();

//Using tuples for joins to keep everything strongly-typed
var subscribableType = typeof(Tuple<int, string>);
var doubleTuple = Type.GetType("System.Tuple`2, mscorlib", true);

foreach (var alertType in alertTypes)
{
  Type foreignKeyType = GetForeignKeyType(alertType);
  if (foreignKeyType == null)
    continue;

  IQueryable<Alert> unnotifiedAlerts = dataContext.Alerts.Where(a => a.NotificationsSent == null);

  //Generates: .OfType<alertType>()
  MethodCallExpression alertsOfType = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("OfType").MakeGenericMethod(alertType), unnotifiedAlerts.Expression);

  //Generates: .ToList(), which is required for joins on Tuples
  MethodCallExpression unnotifiedAlertsList = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("ToList").MakeGenericMethod(alertType), alertsOfType);

  //Generates: a => new { a.{EntityId}, EntityType = typeof(AdAccount).Name }
  ParameterExpression alertParameter = Expression.Parameter(alertType, "a");
  MemberExpression adAccountId = Expression.Property(alertParameter, alertType.GetProperty(alertType.GetForeignKeyId()));
  NewExpression outerJoinObject = Expression.New(subscribableType.GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(int), typeof(string)}), adAccountId, Expression.Constant(foreignKeyType.Name));
  LambdaExpression outerSelector = Expression.Lambda(outerJoinObject, alertParameter);

  //Generates: s => new { s.EntityId, s.EntityType }
  Type alertSubscriptionType = typeof(AlertSubscription);
  ParameterExpression subscriptionParameter = Expression.Parameter(alertSubscriptionType, "s");
  MemberExpression entityId = Expression.Property(subscriptionParameter, alertSubscriptionType.GetProperty("EntityId"));
  MemberExpression entityType = Expression.Property(subscriptionParameter, alertSubscriptionType.GetProperty("EntityType"));
  NewExpression innerJoinObject = Expression.New(subscribableType.GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(int), typeof(string) }), entityId, entityType);
  LambdaExpression innerSelector = Expression.Lambda(innerJoinObject, subscriptionParameter);

  //Generates: (Alert, Subscribers) => new Tuple<Alert, IEnumerable<AlertSubscription>>(Alert, Subscribers)
  var joinResultType = doubleTuple.MakeGenericType(new Type[] { alertType, typeof(IEnumerable<AlertSubscription>) });
  ParameterExpression alertTupleParameter = Expression.Parameter(alertType, "Alert");
  ParameterExpression subscribersTupleParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IEnumerable<AlertSubscription>), "Subscribers");
  NewExpression joinResultObject = Expression.New(
    joinResultType.GetConstructor(new Type[] { alertType, typeof(IEnumerable<AlertSubscription>) }),
    alertTupleParameter,
    subscribersTupleParameter);

  LambdaExpression resultsSelector = Expression.Lambda(joinResultObject, alertTupleParameter, subscribersTupleParameter);

  //Generates:
  //  .GroupJoin(dataContext.AlertSubscriptions,
  //    a => new { a.AdAccountId, typeof(AdAccount).Name },
  //    s => new { s.EntityId, s.EntityType },
  //    (Alert, Subscribers) => new Tuple<Alert, IEnumerable<AlertSubscription>>(Alert, Subscribers))
  IQueryable<AlertSubscription> alertSubscriptions = dataContext.AlertSubscriptions.AsQueryable();
  MethodCallExpression joinExpression = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable),
    "GroupJoin",
    new Type[]
    {
      alertType,
      alertSubscriptions.ElementType,
      outerSelector.Body.Type,
      resultsSelector.ReturnType
    },
    unnotifiedAlertsList,
    alertSubscriptions.Expression,
    outerSelector,
    innerSelector,
    resultsSelector);

  //Generates: .Where(s => s.Item2.Any())
  ParameterExpression subscribersParameter = Expression.Parameter(resultsSelector.ReturnType, "s");
  MemberExpression tupleSubscribers = Expression.Property(subscribersParameter, resultsSelector.ReturnType.GetProperty("Item2"));
  MethodCallExpression hasSubscribers = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable),
    "Any",
    new Type[] { alertSubscriptions.ElementType },
    tupleSubscribers);
  LambdaExpression whereLambda = Expression.Lambda(hasSubscribers, subscriptionParameter);
  MethodCallExpression whereExpression = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable),
    "Where",
    new Type[] { joinResultType },
    joinExpression,
    whereLambda);
```

Comment: Just one question: do you think that the code you're writing is easily readable and maintainable?

Comment: The real code is broken down into separate functions that makes it a bit easier to read. I put everything together here for context.

If you're inquiring about my use of dynamically building expression trees, as I stated in the post, it's been the best option I've found so far. PredicateBuilder doesn't do the job, nor did the DynamicLinq library.

Comment: It is all fine, I was just wondering because you put everything in context; I understand what you mean.

Comment: I can't make any sense out of what the original LINQ is trying to do in the first place, let alone the dynamically generated LINQ.

Comment: What exactly is the problem with your current code? How does it fail? Have you tried comparing the expression tree that you generate and the one generated by C# from the lambda?

Comment: I've updated the code with some comments at the top as to what the original LINQ query attempts to do.

As to my problem, everything works great until the Where() statement, where it blows up, because I'm not using the right type, which I believe is because of my Any() method call.

Yes I've tried comparing my expression tree to the C# lambda. Everything looks exactly right, but it doesn't like the type in my whereExpression declaration.

Comment: Don't want to bash, but why is this useful? I mean, the original query is so specific that it would require tons of specifications to direct your expression builder to the same result. Almost like writing the query itself. Side note: if you don't use `Tuple`, but anonymous types you can do without `ToList` until just before `ToDictionary`.

Comment: The "original" query is specific only to give anyone looking at this context. As per my original question, the real code iterates through all classes that implement an interface (IAlert) and seeks to build the "original" query for each alert type.

I realize I can use anonymous types, but that's a bad hack that doesn't give you any strong-typing. I found it more difficult to build the expression trees that way.

Comment: I haven't reviewed the APIs involved, but `Where` expects and `Any` returns a `Boolean`, and I don't see that type mentioned anywhere.

Comment: Also, if you can confirm your generated query is fine without the `.Where` clause (except that the `.Select` in the `.ToDictionary` call sometimes returns nothing), you should be able to simply confirm the code required to generate the equivalent of `Enumerable.Range(0,2).Select(i=>Enumerable.Range(0,i)).Where(r=>r.Any())`, and then a "simple" extension such that the `.Where` clause becomes `r.item2.Any()`.

Comment: You need to tell us where the error occurred, the exact message and more information about the runtime values of all the expressions involved. Right now this is a sea of code. Hard to find any problems with it. **Can you condense it to a 10 line repro?!**

Comment: variables of anonymous types are strongly typed as any other variable. The type is anonymous so you don't know the name of it but it's there just the same

Answer (score 3):

Please note: Everything after and including `ToList()` won't work on `IQueryable<T>` but on `IEnumerable<T>`. Because of this, there is no need to create expression trees. It certainly is nothing that is interpreted by EF or similar.

If you would look at the code that is generated by the compiler for your original query, you would see that it generates expression trees only until just before the first call to `ToList`.

Example:

The following code:

```
var query = new List<int>().AsQueryable();
query.Where(x => x > 0).ToList().FirstOrDefault(x => x > 10);
```

Is translated by the compiler to this:

```
IQueryable<int> query = new List<int>().AsQueryable<int>();
IQueryable<int> arg_4D_0 = query;
ParameterExpression parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "x");
arg_4D_0.Where(Expression.Lambda<Func<int, bool>>(Expression.GreaterThan(parameterExpression, Expression.Constant(0, typeof(int))), new ParameterExpression[]
{
    parameterExpression
})).ToList<int>().FirstOrDefault((int x) => x > 10);
```

Please note how it generates expressions for everything up to `ToList`. Everything after and including it are simply normal calls to extension methods.

If you don't mimick this in your code, you will actually send a call to `Enumerable.ToList` to the LINQ provider - which it then tries to convert to SQL and fail.

Comment: _"Because of this, there is no need to create expression trees."_ => Except that the query he wants to write depends on types that are not known at compile time, so yes, he needs to construct it dynamically.

Comment: @MikeStrobel If you mean the OP needs to construct things dynamically after the `ToList`, then sure, but that doesn't need to be and probably shouldn't be done using expression trees. And omitting expression trees where they aren't needed greatly simplifies the question.

Comment: If the types and properties aren't known at compile time, what should he do instead?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, when constructing `whereLambda`, your second parameter should be `subscribersParameter` and not `subscriptionParameter`.  At least, that would be the cause of your exception.